# How to properly convert json array in axios query parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, axios

i struggle to do something that look simple with axios :

Here is my axios query :

```
axios.get('/consumption_reports', {
    params: {
        exists: {
            energyDeliveryPoint : false
        }
     }
})
```

The result is this query :

`consumption_reports?exists={"energyDeliveryPoint":false}`

When i would like this result :

`consumption_reports?exists[energyDeliveryPoint]=false`

I tried many different solution but could not found the one that works.
I look forward any answer that keep code simple.
PS : I do not want to hard code the url with my desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [works with Axios 1.x](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-river-6h9ibg?file=/src/index.js)

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const {data} = await axios.get('http://httpbin.org/get', {
  params: {
    exists: {
      energyDeliveryPoint : false
    }
  }
});

console.log(axios.VERSION, data.url); // 1.3.0 http://httpbin.org/get?exists[energyDeliveryPoint]=false
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually yes it work in axios 1.x and you helped me notify that my axios version was a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found myself, in that case i have no choice to do this :

```
axios.get('/consumption_reports', {
    params: {
        "exists[energyDeliveryPoint]": false
    }
})
```